# flutter local notification does not send notifications

Tags: flutter, android-notifications, flutter-local-notification, flutter-notification

```
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();


    // initialization of flutter local notifications plugin
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

    int hour = int.parse(selectedTime.hour.toString());
    int minute = int.parse(selectedTime.minute.toString());
    final alarmId = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.remainder(100000);
    );

    // scheduling local notification
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        newAlarm.id,
        'Alarm',
        'Alarm ${hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} için ayarlandı',
        scheduledDate,
        const NotificationDetails(
            iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
              sound: 'a_long_cold_sting.wav',
              presentAlert: true,
              presentBadge: true,
              presentSound: true,
            ),
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                'alarm_channel', 'Alarm Channel',
                channelDescription: 'Alarm Channel',
                importance: Importance.high,
                priority: Priority.high,
                enableVibration: true,
                playSound: true,
                sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('default_alarm'),
                showWhen: false)),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        payload: newAlarm.name,
        matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.dayOfWeekAndTime);

    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

permissions granted and checked that the alarm has been added

The purpose of the code is to add an alarm on a page and process it in the database and trigger the notification when the time comes, but the notification does not appear even though the alarm is added without any problems.

Comment: If you are checking it on android 12 or 13 then need notification permission to be on

Comment: permissions granted and added to manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
```

with

```
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
```

so that can wait till notifications plugin is initialize.

you must provide background service to make your idea work well you have 2 of the most efficient packages

1. [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) also check this [example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/background-local-notifications-in-flutter/)
2. [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) also check the example on the website (example section)